# UWP Project Cant Connect VPN (E_ACCESSDENIED)

Tags: c#, uwp

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ConnectVPNProfile();
    }
    private async Task ConnectVPNProfile()
    {
        string vpnProfileName = "MyVPNProfileName";

        string[] epdg = { "MyVPN.DomainName.org" };
        VpnManagementErrorStatus status = VpnManagementErrorStatus.Ok;
        IAsyncOperation<VpnManagementErrorStatus> op;

        var vpnMa = new VpnManagementAgent();
        var vpnProfile = new VpnNativeProfile();
        vpnProfile.AlwaysOn = true;
        vpnProfile.ProfileName = vpnProfileName;
        vpnProfile.RequireVpnClientAppUI = true;
        vpnProfile.RememberCredentials = true;
        vpnProfile.RoutingPolicyType = VpnRoutingPolicyType.SplitRouting;
        vpnProfile.TunnelAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod.Eap;
        vpnProfile.UserAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod.Eap;
        foreach (var s in epdg)
        {
            vpnProfile.Servers.Add(s);
        }

        vpnProfile.EapConfiguration = GetEapXmlString();

        // Adds the profile using the management api.
        status = await vpnMa.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(vpnProfile);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Add profile: {status}");

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        op = vpnMa.ConnectProfileAsync(vpnProfile);
        status = await op;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Connect succeeded: {status}");


    }


    public static string GetEapXmlString()
    {
        //string template = "<EapHostConfig xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig\"><EapMethod><Type xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon\">25</Type><VendorId xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon\">0</VendorId><VendorType xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon\">0</VendorType><AuthorId xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon\">0</AuthorId></EapMethod><Config xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig\"><Eap xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1\"><Type>25</Type><EapType xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV1\"><ServerValidation><DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>true</DisableUserPromptForServerValidation><ServerNames></ServerNames><TrustedRootCA>d2 d3 8e ba 60 ca a1 c1 20 55 a2 e1 c8 3b 15 ad 45 01 10 c2 </TrustedRootCA><TrustedRootCA>d1 76 97 cc 20 6e d2 6e 1a 51 f5 bb 96 e9 35 6d 6d 61 0b 74 </TrustedRootCA></ServerValidation><FastReconnect>true</FastReconnect><InnerEapOptional>false</InnerEapOptional><Eap xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1\"><Type>13</Type><EapType xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTlsConnectionPropertiesV1\"><CredentialsSource><CertificateStore><SimpleCertSelection>true</SimpleCertSelection></CertificateStore></CredentialsSource><ServerValidation><DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>true</DisableUserPromptForServerValidation><ServerNames></ServerNames><TrustedRootCA>d2 d3 8e ba 60 ca a1 c1 20 55 a2 e1 c8 3b 15 ad 45 01 10 c2 </TrustedRootCA><TrustedRootCA>d1 76 97 cc 20 6e d2 6e 1a 51 f5 bb 96 e9 35 6d 6d 61 0b 74 </TrustedRootCA></ServerValidation><DifferentUsername>false</DifferentUsername><PerformServerValidation xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTlsConnectionPropertiesV2\">true</PerformServerValidation><AcceptServerName xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTlsConnectionPropertiesV2\">false</AcceptServerName><TLSExtensions xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTlsConnectionPropertiesV2\"><FilteringInfo xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTlsConnectionPropertiesV3\"><EKUMapping><EKUMap><EKUName>AAD Conditional Access</EKUName><EKUOID>1.3.6.1.4.1.311.87</EKUOID></EKUMap></EKUMapping><ClientAuthEKUList Enabled=\"true\"><EKUMapInList><EKUName>AAD Conditional Access</EKUName></EKUMapInList></ClientAuthEKUList></FilteringInfo></TLSExtensions></EapType></Eap><EnableQuarantineChecks>false</EnableQuarantineChecks><RequireCryptoBinding>true</RequireCryptoBinding><PeapExtensions><PerformServerValidation xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV2\">true</PerformServerValidation><AcceptServerName xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV2\">false</AcceptServerName></PeapExtensions></EapType></Eap></Config></EapHostConfig>";
        string template = "<EapHostConfig xmlns =\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig\"><EapMethod><Type xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon\">13</Type><VendorId xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon\">0</VendorId><VendorType xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon\">0</VendorType><AuthorId xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon\">0</AuthorId></EapMethod><Config xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig\"><Eap xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1\"><Type>13</Type><EapType xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTlsConnectionPropertiesV1\"><CredentialsSource><CertificateStore><SimpleCertSelection>true</SimpleCertSelection></CertificateStore></CredentialsSource><ServerValidation><DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>false</DisableUserPromptForServerValidation><ServerNames></ServerNames><TrustedRootCA>b6 ea bf ba 48 be 09 c9 50 4f c6 ea 9b f5 74 dc a9 01 56 62 </TrustedRootCA></ServerValidation><DifferentUsername>false</DifferentUsername><PerformServerValidation xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTlsConnectionPropertiesV2\">false</PerformServerValidation><AcceptServerName xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTlsConnectionPropertiesV2\">false</AcceptServerName><TLSExtensions xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTlsConnectionPropertiesV2\"><FilteringInfo xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapTlsConnectionPropertiesV3\"><CAHashList Enabled=\"true\"><IssuerHash>b6 ea bf ba 48 be 09 c9 50 4f c6 ea 9b f5 74 dc a9 01 56 62 </IssuerHash></CAHashList></FilteringInfo></TLSExtensions></EapType></Eap></Config></EapHostConfig>";
        //TODO: Create propper XML here
        string result = template;

        return result;
    }
}
```

}

i inserted top page this code
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.MarshalingBehavior(Windows.Foundation.Metadata.MarshalingType.Agile)]
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Threading(Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ThreadingModel.MTA)]
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.WebHostHidden]
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Activatable(65536, "Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract")]

Error:System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Erişim engellendi. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

Error Line: status = await vpnMa.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(vpnProfile);

Comment: Did you declare the required capability? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn?view=winrt-19041

Comment: Thank you i solved this problem with your linked document